# Синтаксическая роль выражения

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, какую роль будет выполнять выражение "как пар из чайника" в следующем предложении: "*Камень рвётся наружу, как пар из чайника*"? Обособленным сравнительным оборотом (есть сравнительный союз) или всё-таки придаточным сравнения (по идее можно вставить мысленно глагол рвётся, ведь в этом выражении имеется обстоятельство "из чайника", а обстоятельство в большинстве случаев зависит от сказуемого-глагола)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Камень рвётся наружу, как пар (рвется) из чайника.***

Это неполное придаточное **сравнительное предложение** с пропущенным сказуемым.
В книге Кустовой  «Синтаксис современного русского языка» разбирается подобный пример:

(1) *Бросился бежать, **как заяц*** (сравнительный оборот).

(2) *Бросился бежать, **как заяц от волка*** (придаточное сравнительное).

Comment: Спасибо большое!